# extract each segment from text using regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have this text line:

```
01102574 04 n 02 republication 0 republishing 0 003 @ 01101958 n 0000 ! 01746163 v 0201 + 01746163 v 0101 ! 01758710 v 0541 + 00967643 v 0201
```

And i need to extract the first 8 digits and each segment after a question mark like this :

01102574 ! 01746163 v 0201 ! 01758710 v 0541

I'm using this regex in python:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"""
    ^([0-9]{8})(.*?)\ !\ (([0-9]{8}\ [a-z]{1}\ [0-9]{4}))
    """, re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)
    for match in pattern.finditer(text_in):
output = "%s %s\n" % (match.group(1, 3))
```

My problem is that i can only get the first segment after the question mark and not the others. How can i match the regex against all the segments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `pattern` includes the start of the line - `^`, so you'll only ever get the first.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I tried removing the ^ from regex, but still not working.

Comment: Have you tried using e.g. https://regex101.com/#python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import re

text_in = "01102574 04 n 02 republication 0 republishing 0 003 @ 01101958 n 0000 ! 01746163 v 0201 + 01746163 v 0101 ! 01758710 v 0541 + 00967643 v 0201";

pattern = re.compile("((^[0-9]{8})|(! [0-9]+ [a-z] [0-9]{4}))")

for match in pattern.findall(text_in):
    print match[0]
```

Output:

```
01102574
! 01746163 v 0201
! 01758710 v 0541
```